# Why does Double.compare() compares the numbers twice

Tags: java, double

I was looking at the `Double.compare()` implementation via `F5` in debug mode (copy paste)

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2) {
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;           // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is smaller
    if (d1 > d2)
        return 1;            // Neither val is NaN, thisVal is larger

    // Cannot use doubleToRawLongBits because of possibility of NaNs.
    long thisBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d1);
    long anotherBits = Double.doubleToLongBits(d2);

    return (thisBits == anotherBits ?  0 : // Values are equal
            (thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : // (-0.0, 0.0) or (!NaN, NaN)
             1));                          // (0.0, -0.0) or (NaN, !NaN)
}
```

I was expecting something like

```
public static int compare(double d1, double d2) {
    if (d1 < d2)
        return -1;
    if (d1 > d2)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

But instead of `return 0;` the method converts the doubles to bits and compares again if one of them is bigger than the other

```
thisBits < anotherBits ? -1 : 1);
```

Why is the redundancy of the second comparison?

Comment: The comments are pretty explicit: this is to handle NaN tricky cases.

Comment: maybe try Single.compare()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `d1` is some number like `0.0` and `d2` is `NaN`, then `d1 < d2` will be false and `d1 > d2` will *also* be false, but this does not make `NaN` equal to `d1`.  Additionally, if `d1` is `-0.0` and `d2` is `0.0`, then `d1 < d2` will be `false` and `d1 > d2` will *also* be false, but `0.0` is supposed to be greater than `-0.0`.

The comments make this pretty clear.